# TFDMemTable filtering on Nested dataset

Tags: delphi, filter

Delphi 12:

I have 2 TFDMemTable on has the data and nested data loaded in to it.

The second has its datasetfield set to the Datasetfield on the master MemTable

All data displays, and filtering on the master TFDMemTable works as advertised.

When I try to put a filter on the detail TFDMemTable. Nothing happens.

Can you filter nested datasets?

TIA